# Node express request call inside get

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to use nodejs as a layer between my public website and a server on the inside of our network.

I'm using express.js to create a simple REST api. The API endpoint should trigger a request call to a webservice, and return the result.

But the request call inside my `.get()` function doesn't do anything.

I want to return the result from the nested call to be returned.

Code:

```
// Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request');
//Port
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;  

// Express
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// Routes
app.get('/invoice', function(req, res){
   res.send('Express is workiung on IISNode')
});


app.get('/invoice/api/costumer=:customerId&invoice=:invoiceId',  function(req, res){
       res.send('Customer ID: ' + req.params.customerId + ' Invoice ID: '+ req.params.invoiceId)

      var url = 'http://xxx/invapp/getinvoice?company='+req.params.customerId+'S&customerno=13968&invoiceno='+req.params.invoiceId+'';
      request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
      res.send(body);

      })

});

 // Start server
app.listen(port);
console.log("API is running on port " + port);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you sending response two times?

Comment: You are using 'res.send' in the first line of your 'get' endpoint. That will send the response to the client. Remove this line, and you should be OK.

Comment: That did it! Wow that was easy. Thanks alot. Didn't knwo you weren't able to send twice.

Answer (score 2):

You can write in this way

```
// Dependencies
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request');
//Port
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;  

// Express
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// Routes
app.get('/invoice', function(req, res){
   res.send('Express is working')
});


app.get('/invoice/api/costumer=:customerId&invoice=:invoiceId',  function(req, res){

      var url = 'http://xxx/invapp/getinvoice?company='+req.params.customerId+'S&customerno=13968&invoiceno='+req.params.invoiceId+'';
      request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        var data={
          body:body,
          customerID:req.params.customerId,
          invoiceID:req.params.invoiceId
        };
      res.send(data);
      });    
});

 // Start server
app.listen(port);
console.log("API is running on port " + port);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find the snippet I am using. Hope this helps for you as well.

```
var body="";
function callyourservice(customerId,invoiceId,callback) {
        var options = {
            uri : url + 'costumer=:customerId&invoice=:invoiceId',
            method : 'GET'
        }
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {

            console.log(response);
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                res = body;
            }
            else {
                res = 'Not Found';
            }
            callback(res);
        });
    }



callyourservice("customerId value","invoiceId value", function(resp){

    body=JSON.stringify(resp);;
});
```

You can write `callyourservice` inside a `get` method from client like 
`app.get('/'){
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it the node way using  `pipe`

```
 var http = require('http');

 http.createServer(function(request, response) {
   var proxy = http.createClient(9000, 'localhost')
   var proxyRequest = proxy.request(request.method, request.url, request.headers);
   proxyRequest.on('response', function (proxyResponse) {
     proxyResponse.pipe(response);
   });
   request.pipe(proxyRequest);
 }).listen(8080);

 http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
   res.write('request successfully proxied to port 9000!' + '\n' + JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2));
   res.end();
 }).listen(9000);
```

You can find the reference [here](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/advanced/streams/how-to-use-stream-pipe/)